# Display values until the first space in MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to display values until the first space in MYSQL and PHP. For example,

```
1 items from 29
100 items from 10
```

In the first example I want to display only the number 1, and in the second example I want to display only the number 100 and so on. Here is my code,

```
$ordering = "SELECT t.id, t.cart_id, t.full_name, t.description, t.txn_date, t.grand_total, c.paid, c.shipped
            FROM transactions t
            LEFT JOIN cart c ON t.cart_id = c.id
            WHERE c.paid = 1 AND c.shipped = 0
            ORDER BY t.txn_date
```

Now, I want to replace `t.description` with the code of that displays until the first space. I've searched in the internet and found the code:

```
SELECT REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(YourColumn), LEN(YourColumn) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(YourColumn))))
```

So, I replaced `t.description` with this:

```
$ordering = "SELECT t.id, t.cart_id, t.full_name, t.REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(description), LEN(description) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(description)))), t.txn_date, t.grand_total, c.paid, c.shipped
                FROM transactions t
                LEFT JOIN cart c ON t.cart_id = c.id
                WHERE c.paid = 1 AND c.shipped = 0
                ORDER BY t.txn_date
```

Is that right? And what is the best way to it?

Comment: can you be more clear? what first space means?

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in detail? "first space in MYSQL" what does that mean?

Comment: Also you can do this in php like `$array = explode(' ', $description,2);` and you will get 100 for `$array[0]`

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, the easiest way to do this is with [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) e.g.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('100 items from 10', ' ', 1)
```

With a positive third parameter (`count`, in this case 1), it returns everything to the left of the `count` occurrence of the second parameter (in this case space). So this call returns everything to the left of the first space:

```
100
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=291ad3ce68f924984772a3500dcd5c61)

In your query you would write

```
$ordering = "SELECT t.id, t.cart_id, t.full_name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.description, ' ', 1) AS description, t.txn_date, t.grand_total, c.paid, c.shipped
            FROM transactions t
            LEFT JOIN cart c ON t.cart_id = c.id
            WHERE c.paid = 1 AND c.shipped = 0
            ORDER BY t.txn_date
```